# My App crashes because of the heightConstraints I don't know how to fix it

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

When I comment out the constraints it works perfectly, but the problem is the height of the `textfield` becomes too small, when I add the `heightConstraint`, it works fine in my `iPhone XS Max`, but crashes in other Iphones...

```
lazy var textField: MaterialTexField = { //MaterialTexField

    let tf = MaterialTexField()
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(tf)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tf.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant:16.0),
        tf.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant:-16.0),
        tf.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant:8.0),
        tf.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 1),
//This is the problematic constraints
        tf.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo:self.contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier:0.9)

    return tf

}()
```

Comment: may you forgot `constant:`

Comment: Conflicting constraints `tf.bottomAnchor` and `tf.heightAnchor`. Try to use only height constraint. And take a look at constant value, nearby multiplier.

Comment: "but crashes in other Iphones..." Maybe some crash log could help...

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try this

```
tf.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 1.0),
```

instead of

```
tf.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 1),
```

Comment: This is why I don't like doing constraints programmatically.... I've been trying to solve this for 2 days..

Comment: I my.... it worked... I comment out the height constraint then use your code it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 1)
```

Try this first, if this doesnot solve your problem then remove **bottomanchor**

Either use **heightConstraint** or use **topAnchor and bottomAnchor**. Don't use both cause xcode will not understand what to do, you are just making it confuses by giving **height and autolayout**.